# Foundation CSS Framework, how to change triangle on accodion

Tags: css, css-frameworks

I'm using [foundation framework](http://foundation.zurb.com/) for the first time and for the most part everything is going smoothly. I am however having some trouble with the accordion in that I need to change the open/close indicator triangle that is in use. You can see it in the [docs here](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/elements.php#accEx). I've looked through the css and found the section with the accordion on foundation.css at lines 709-719 but there is no image to change or adjust.

I would like to change this icon to the one in my psd, but just can't figure out where. See attached screenshot for what needs to be changed.[image]

I know how to make changes, in this case I just can't find where to make the change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't find the image, because it's not an image. It's one section of a thick border on a small square. One side is grey, the other sides are transparent to create the triangle effect.

See "presentation.css" line 852:

```
ul.accordion > li.active .title::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: solid 6px;
    border-color: #9D9D9D transparent transparent transparent;
}
```

I used Google Chrome's object inspector.